# How to add a column from a row in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Spreadsheets how can I convert this table

[image: From]

into this

[image: To]

Comment: Why on earth is this question down voted?

Answer (score -1):

Try if this will work for you:

Assuming that your data in your sample is in a1:c4...

```
Column D (Task1/2) = transpose(split(concatenate(arrayformula(left(A2:A4&B1:C1,5)
&ʺ-ʺ)),ʺ-ʺ))

Column E (NY/NJ)   = transpose(split(concatenate(arrayformula(right(A2:A4&B1:C1,2)
&ʺ-ʺ)),ʺ-ʺ))

Column F (a/b/c)   = vlookup(D2,$A$1:$C$5,match(E2,$A$1:$C$1,0),false)
```

*The formula above only works for 3 rows. If you have more rows, change the range `(A2:A4)` in Column D and E and the vlookup range `($A$1:$C$5)`

---

If you don't have a fixed number of rows try this instead:

```
Column D (Task1/2) = transpose(split(concatenate(filter(arrayformula(left(A2:
A&B1:C1,5)&ʺ-ʺ),A2:A<>ʺʺ)),ʺ-ʺ))

 Column E (NY/NJ)   =transpose(split(concatenate(filter(arrayformula(right(A2:
 A&B1:C1,2)&ʺ-ʺ),A2:A<>ʺʺ)),ʺ-ʺ))
```

Column `F (a/b/c)`   = **I will need help on this (arrayformula for 2-dimentional look-up)

---

edit:

this may work for Column

```
    F (a/b/c):= transpose(split(concatenate(filter(arrayformula(B2:B&ʺ-ʺ&C2:C&ʺ-ʺ)
,B2:B<>ʺʺ)),ʺ-ʺ))
```

Comment: Thank you. But I get "Parse Error" on every of these formulas. Let me take a closer look tomorrow though.

Comment: You'll have to remove the spaces after "=". It's an editing mistake when I was collecting the formulas to notepad.

Comment: Disregard the comment above. I can't edit it right away. Let me check as well. I have the same formulas but pasting them from this page is also giving me an error. Pasting from w/in the sheet works though. See for yourself:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ang7X5PWs84GdDAwRUJvekNzYnFFWDlNdlZ3VjlORmc&usp=sharing